# prolog change show answer to print into list

Tags: list, printing, prolog

Here is a piece of code which is used to print squares out:

```
show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol) :-
  show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,1), nl.

show_result(_,MaxRow,_,Row) :- Row > MaxRow, !.
show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,Row) :- 
   show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,Row,1), nl,
   Row1 is Row+1, show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,Row1).

show_result(_,_,MaxCol,_,Col) :- Col > MaxCol, !. 
show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,Row,Col) :- 
   (memberchk(sq(Row,Col,X),Squares), !, write(X); write('#')).
   Col1 is Col+1, show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,Row,Col1).
```

After running `show_result([sq(1,2,'c'),sq(2,1,'A'),sq(2,2,'a'),sq(2,3,'C'),sq(3,2,'t')],3,3)`
it will give a result:

```
#c#
AaC
#t#
```

How can I store the result into a list, which has the format:`[[#,c,#],[A,a,C],[#t#]]`?
Can anyone write the function: `show_result(Squares, MaxRow, MaxCol,result)`?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Why is it `[#c#]` and not `[#,c,#]`?

Comment: yes. you are right. Sorry for the typo mistake. It should be [#,c,#].Do you have any idea to figure out the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When describing a list, always consider using DCGs. In your case, you can very easily obtain what you want with a few simple modifications to your code:

```
show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol, List) :-
    phrase(show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,1), List).

show_result(_,MaxRow,_,Row) --> { Row > MaxRow }, !.
show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,Row) -->
    { phrase(show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,Row,1), Line) } ,
    [Line],
    { Row1 is Row+1 },
    show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,Row1).

show_result(_,_,MaxCol,_,Col) --> { Col > MaxCol }, !. 
show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,Row,Col) -->
    ( { memberchk(sq(Row,Col,X),Squares) } ->  
        [X]
    ;   [#]
    ),
    { Col1 is Col+1 },
    show_result(Squares,MaxRow,MaxCol,Row,Col1).
```

Example query and its result:

```
?- show_result([sq(1,2,'c'),sq(2,1,'A'),sq(2,2,'a'),sq(2,3,'C'),sq(3,2,'t')], 3, 3, List).
List = [[#, c, #], ['A', a, 'C'], [#, t, #]]
```